# How to read string parameters from stack in nasm

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, calling-convention

I am wondering how to get a string I am being passed from a C function to an assembly procedure. The calling function is like this: `const char* reversed = reverse_string("abcd");` where reverse string is an externally defined function defined like this: `extern "C" const char* __cdecl reverse_string(const char*);`.

By now on the assembly procedure, I have tried to do `mov ebx, [ebp + 8]` to try to get the value of the first letter of the parameter (as I have done with integers in previuous exercises) but doesn´t seem to work.

Is there anything I am doing or understanding wrong here? Or is there a special way of reading string paremeters from the stack?

Comment: `mov ebx, [ebp+8]` will get you the pointer to the string, then you need to use `[ebx]` to get at the first character.

Comment: thanks, that got the string!

Comment: You don't need that LEA for integers either, just use an `[ebp+8]` addressing mode for `mov` like a normal person.  Avoiding address-calculation instructions is the whole point of x86 having powerful addressing modes.